# Is Western Digital's Data Lifeguard Diagnostic tool a reliable way to ensure a disk's trustworthiness?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm considering using a used drive (that was pulled from a desktop for being the suspect cause for data corruption) in a new (used) server. I ran WD's data life guard diagnostics on it and it passed everything. Anyone have enough experience with WD's dlg tools to give me some reassurance here?

Comment: No matter what test the drive may pass with flying colors, make sure it has a RAID-1 (or better) buddy drive in that new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run smartmontools.

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki

they will give you the more reliable info.
run a long test and see what comes out

linux/unix syntax:

smartctl --test=long /dev/sda